# Обновить колонку в таблице значением переданным как аргумент

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

Возможно ли обновить колонку в таблице значением переданным как аргумент?

Есть код:

```
import sqlite3

def AddName(X):
    with sqlite3.connect('Base.db') as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        query='''  UPDATE base set name = X where Id = 123  '''
        cursor.execute(query)

AddName(5)
```

Нужно, чтобы значение колонки `name` обновилось значением X, взятым из переданного аргумаента.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше сделать так:

```
def update_name(cursor, name, id):
    query=f'UPDATE base set name = ? where Id = ?'
    cursor.execute(query, params=(name, id))

with sqlite3.connect('Base.db') as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    update_name(cursor, name=5, id=123)
    # ... дальнейшая работа с курсором ...
    cursor.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Один из вариантов решения вашей проблемы - использование форматирования строк.

Вот простой пример:

```
import sqlite3

def AddName(X):
    with sqlite3.connect('Base.db') as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        query=f'UPDATE base set name = {X} where Id = 123'
        cursor.execute(query)
AddName(5)
```

Но не забывайте использовать экранирование для предотвращения sql-инъекций.

```
def AddName(X):
    with sqlite3.connect('Base.db') as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('UPDATE base set name = ? where Id = ?', (X, 123))
AddName(5)
```

Comment: Это ОЧЕНЬ опасный код. SQL Injections ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, я указал ниже - что следует использовать экранирование;)

Comment: @MaxU, возможно я ошибся, утверждать не буду.

Comment: Кажется можно удалить все из таблицы вот так: `X = "something WHERE id = 123; DELETE FROM base; SELECT * FROM base "`... Причем тут "экранирование"?'

Comment: @MaxU, да, вы абсолютно правы. Я это и подразумевал.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, в примере, который я привел - действительно это возможно. Но я подразумевал использование `?` для sql-запросов.

Comment: Ну, понятно... Ну тогда может не надо опасные ответы писать или лучше добавлять дисклеймер?